# DiscriminatorMap Symfony 5.4 change foreign key

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have this class

```
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\InheritanceType('JOINED')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name: 'type', type: 'integer')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorMap([
    1 => Successor1::class,
])]
abstract class Type
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER)]
    private int $id;


    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}

#[ORM\Entity]
class Successor1 extends Type
{

}
```

By default doctrine made foreign key by ID how to change it to like this

[shema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTQhW.png)

Or type_id on **type** table